# I don't want to show Header & Footer on Error page in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hi I am new in React JS and I don't know how to work with react router dom. Actually I don't want to show Header & Footer on Error page in React JS

```
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Header />
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home popup={showVideoPopup} />} />
                    <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
                    <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
                    <Route exact path="/faq" element={<Faq />} />
                    <Route exact path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />} />
                    <Route exact path="/disclaimer" element={<Disclaimer />} />
                    <Route exact path="/terms-conditions" element={<TermsConditions />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
                </Routes>
                <Footer />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a layout route that renders the `Header` and `Footer` components, and an `Outlet` component for nested routes.

[Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their
> child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child
> routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will
> render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PageLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render out here
    <Footer />
  </>
);
```

Render the `PageLayout` component on a route and wrap all but the error route.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<PageLayout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home popup={showVideoPopup} />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/faq" element={<Faq />} />
          <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />} />
          <Route path="/disclaimer" element={<Disclaimer />} />
          <Route path="/terms-conditions" element={<TermsConditions />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router';
const Error = (props)=>{
    useEffect(()=>props.handleShow(false),[]);
    return <>Error Page</>
}

function App() {
const {id} = useParams()
const [show,setShow] = useState(true);
   useEffect(()=>{
      setShow(true)
   },[id])
  return (
    <>
        <BrowserRouter>
            {show&&<Header />}
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Home popup={showVideoPopup} />} />
                <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
                <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
                <Route exact path="/faq" element={<Faq />} />
                <Route exact path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />} />
                <Route exact path="/disclaimer" element={<Disclaimer />} />
                <Route exact path="/terms-conditions" element={<TermsConditions />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Error handleShow={(res)=>setShow(false)} />} />
            </Routes>
            {show&&<Footer />}
        </BrowserRouter>
    </>
);
}

export default App;
```